# Template class in Java

Tags: java

Suppose that there is a class called Test like this

```
public class Test<A extends X, B extends Y> {
    public int testing(long n) {
       a(new Good(n));
       return 1;
   }
}
```

I want to use this class as `Test<Good, Bad>`. 
`Good` class is constructed by long type, but this doesn't work because a function in testing requires A type, not `Good`. In this case what can I do to use `A` type?

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding what you're trying to do. Why is `Test` generic when you never make use of it? What is going on with `Good`? What does `a()` do? I think we'll need some clarifications here

Comment: Have only the vaguest idea what those words mean. Please improve question.

Comment: You need to include far more, considering `Good` and `Bad` are not included even though they are quite obviously required for this example. Also it is probably `Long`, not `long`. ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: Unable to understand your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to instantiate an object of type A inside your template class. The templated class will only be visible at runtime, so you'll have to use reflection. As a quick example -

```
public class LongConstructInitializer<T>{

  public void initT(T t){
    try{
        Constructor<?> constructor = t.getClass().getConstructor(Long.class);
        T anotherT = constructor.newInstance(4L);
    } //Giant catch block goes here.
  }
```

The fact that you want to do this makes me think you're misusing generics, though. You may want to rethink the design of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer being not sure what is the purpose or the problem; but trying to understand your goal. 
It seems what you want is a simple `enum`, not sure if you'll need to wrap it.

```
enum TestTypes {
   GOOD, BAD;
}

public class Test {
    private TestTypes result;

    public Test(TestTypes aResult) {
       this.result = aResult;
    }

// ---- APART -----

public int testing(long l) {
   Test t = new Test(TestTypes.GOOD);
   // do smth with t
    return 1;
}
```